# In Android Studio, how to *undo*, accidentally reverted local changes?

Tags: android-studio

Accidentally pressed revert on my local changes instead of commit, is there any way that I can bring back may changes? something like undo action for reverted local changes is what I am after?

Luckily I had small change and easily redone them but it worth to know if there is a way to do so in case for future need.

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1. Right Click on The explorer's top file (your project name)
2. tap on Local history -> show history
3. undo the revert action from the history time line(see the image) revert the revert ! :)
   [image]

Thanks to answer from `salsinga` helped me to find out a solution.
the only problem is when you deleted a file or created a new file in local changes and just reverted that everything is gone (it does not exists in your explorer) so you do not have access to to the file to right click and see the history of it.

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio has a code history feature which allows you to see previous versions of any file, right click on a file in the IDE's file explorer and you will see the desired option. This link might be helpful : https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/android-studio-local-history